# No page numbering for the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering

How do I skip numbering until the beginning of chapter 1 with `scrbook`?

I'm using something alone the lines of

```
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{none}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{My first chapter}
```

in the beginning of the book, but the table of contents is still numbered, so chapter 1 is on page 3. How do I completely skip numbering until the beginning of chapter 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about `\pagenumbering{none}`. On the other hand, the combination of `\pagenumbering{gobble}` and `\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic}` does what you want. (Note that `\pagenumbering` also resets the `page` counter to 1.)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\author{Me}
\title{My work}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```