# number of page starting after the table of contents

Tags: page-numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No page numbering for the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15419/no-page-numbering-for-the-table-of-contents)

I would like to start numbering the pages of my document after the table of contents. I would like to put the number of pages with the introduction how I can do that please?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{document} 
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\include{title-content}
\color{black}
\tableofcontents
\doublespacing
\listoftables
\listoffigures
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Introduction générale}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15419/no-page-numbering-for-the-table-of-contents. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: I take a look to the information and this is my code    \begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\include{title-content}
\color{black}

\tableofcontents
\doublespacing
\listoftables
\listoffigures



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\chapter{Introduction générale}
\pagenumbering{arabic}    but the number of page start with 2 in the intoduction but I want that start with 1

Comment: I have edited your post to include your code directly in your question, with proper formatting, rather than squeezing it into a comment. In the future, you can do that yourself by clicking the "edit" button at the bottom of your post. Also, it is easier for people to help you if your code is directly compilable (it should include the `\documentclass` and all the packages required). As suggested by lockstep, there may already be a question dealing with your issue. If your problem is different, please edit your question to explain the differences.

Comment: If I take your code snippet, add `\documentclass{book}` and remove the lines with `\include`, `\color`, and `\doublespacing`, the Introduction starts correctly with page 1.

Comment: @lockstep: thank you very much the problem is resolved